# How to view with this query on apache drill

Tags: sql, hadoop, apache-drill

I need help.

I have data like this:

```
anum    bnum
8661994 8661993
8661994 8661993
8661994 8661993
8661992 8661994
```

In SQL I can do something like this:

```
SELECT
anum,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM dataku t2
    WHERE t2.anum=t1.anum
),
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM dataku t3
    WHERE t3.bnum=t1.anum
)
FROM dataku t1
GROUP BY t1.anum;
```

result:

```
anum       count_anum      count_anum_on_bnum
8661992    1                0
8661994    3                1
```

how can I achieve that in apache drill? (data is in csv) 
I tried this, but gave me error

```
SELECT
anum,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM hdfs.`/test/*` as t2
    WHERE t2.anum=t1.anum
),
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM hdfs.`/test/*` as t3
    WHERE t3.anum=t1.anum
)
FROM hdfs.`/test/*` as t1
GROUP BY t1.anum
LIMIT 1000
```

the error is:
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: PLAN ERROR: Cannot convert RexNode to equivalent Drill expression. RexNode Class: org.apache.calcite.rex.RexCorrelVariable, RexNode Digest: $cor1 [Error Id: 7e975eb8-ab37-432f-9387-99126f1f43cf on master:31010]

csv configuration in hdfs

```
"csv": {
  "type": "text",
  "extensions": [
    "csv"
  ],
  "delimiter": ","
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `"extractHeader": true` property to your CSV format plugin and use the following query:

```
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> select t1.anum, t1.count_anum, coalesce(t2.count_bnum, 0) as count_anum_on_bnum from 
. . . . . . . . . . . > (select anum, count(anum) as `count_anum` from dfs.`/tmp/test.csv` group by anum) t1
. . . . . . . . . . . > left join 
. . . . . . . . . . . > (select bnum, count(bnum) as `count_bnum` from dfs.`/tmp/test.csv` group by bnum) t2
. . . . . . . . . . . > on t1.anum = t2.bnum;
+----------+-------------+---------------------+
|   anum   | count_anum  | count_anum_on_bnum  |
+----------+-------------+---------------------+
| 8661992  | 1           | 0                   |
| 8661994  | 3           | 1                   |
+----------+-------------+---------------------+
2 rows selected (0.167 seconds)
```

Drill can't plan the query provided by. You can submit a Jira ticket to implement it:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/DRILL

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on Drill 1.13 and saw NPE issue. 
Have few questions:
Which version of Drill is this?
Also, can you paste the configuration used for "csv" in your DFS storage plugin.

For instance, i have this:

```
 "csv": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "csv"
      ],
      "extractHeader": true,
      "delimiter": ","
    }
```

Comment: please see the post, I updated it. I think it's simply because apache drill not support that kind of query?

Comment: @RichardOctovianus Add "extractHeader": true and Please check the advice by Vitalli given below and go according to it.